# Play youtube video in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiwebview, youtube

I have been trying to figure out how to play a youtube video in an my application without leaving and going to the YouTube App. I have read to embed it into a UIWebView and I tried that but I did not have any success with that at all.

I did something like the following

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe width="560" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/q5WBsBDXqDs?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I even tried using the old embed function, but it is not working for me at all. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I tried it in the the browser and it works just fine, but it does not work in the UIWebView! This is frustrating as to why it does not work.

Comment: How will this even work? iPhone doesn't support flash.

Comment: iframes do, but iPhone doesn't as far as I know

Comment: check those links on an iPhone. They work.

Comment: This technique does not work anymore on iOS6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/360idev-iphone-developers-conference-presentation

For reference: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

Here is another one http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/61447-how-play-youtube-movie.html

I believe this should be enough.

Comment: The code that youtube provided from your second link seems to be working for me. It must have had something to do with the meta content tag. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Three20 has support for youtube "views":

http://three20.info/

http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_you_tube_view.php

Comment: Nice find! Didn't think it was possible.

Comment: Three20 has been discontinued and is no longer supported.